# tilde between Figure (or Table) and number when \ref{...} with chemstyle and babel spanish

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, spanish, tilde, chemstyle

When I reference a figure or table in the text using `\ref{something}` it appears a tilde between *Figura* (or *Tabla*) and the number (something like *Figura~1*), but I realized it's only when using packages `chemstyle`and `[spanish]{babel}`

Here you have a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{chemstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{lion}
\caption{esto es un león}\label{fig-lion}
\end{figure}
bla bla \ref{fig-lion} bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

I use TexShop on a Mac with OSX 10.10. The composition is done with LaTeX (pdfTex).

Is there any incompatibility between `chemstyle`and `[spanish]{babel}`? or any error of my settings?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried with some different languages and I've found it happens in `spanish` and `galician`. For catalan, italian, portuguese, french, romanian, latin, english, german, dutch, finnish, swedish... it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a flaw in how `babel` handles active characters in labels. There are two options:

```
\usepackage[spanish.notilde]{babel}
```

or:

```
\usepackage[spanish,safe=none]{babel}
```

Comment: only the second option worked for me ( `\usepackage[spanish.notilde, es-tabla]{babel}` didn't work) as I'm using `es-tabla` in order to have _Tabla_ instead of _Cuadro_, like this `\usepackage[spanish,safe=none, es-tabla]{babel}`

Comment: Write either `spanish.tabla.notilde` or `spanish,es-tabla,es-notilde`.

Comment: OK! now both options work